# How to remove left padding from UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, imageedgeinsets, titleedgeinsets

**How to remove left `padding` from `UIButton`?**

I have been created button with this code:

```
let button = UIButton(...)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "plus")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
button.setTitle("Text", for: .normal)
button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
button.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

[image: UIButton]

Comment: Does simple button.setTitle("+ Text") works ? (aka, without embedding real image)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to adjust the imageEdgeInsets and titleEdgeInsets with some negative left value. Then it will shift to left. I tested it's working. 100 is temp value.

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: -100.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: -100.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
```

Let me know if it is not working.

Comment: not working swift 5

Answer (score 1):

This line could fix your issue

```
button.titleEdgeInsets.left = 0 // add left padding.
```

Or maybe you could use negative value in this case

There is also this way :

```
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
```

Just try different values !

Comment: if it still doesnt work it's mean that your image is too big and you should resize it